# Filtering Replication Sets for Top 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, merge-replication

I have a Replication Set that we use in Merge Replication(SQL 2005). I am trying to figure out how to apply a Filter of Top 2 to a table.

Also, is there a way to set up a Filter so that it trickles down to sub-tables or would I need to handle that differently?

What I am looking at is a Database of Plans that I am Replicating to our users' laptops. I would like to only Replicate the last two Plans and only replicate the associated data for those two plans. Example, there is a Medication table that lists all the Medication associated to a certain Plan. I would only want to replicate the rows on the Medication table that are tied to one of the Top 2 plans.

I am not sure how I should go about this. I see the Filter option in the Publication Properties but it is by table and I don't seem to have the option of Top 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering can only be done via the WHERE clause.  What you would need to put into the filter is something like this.

```
WHERE PlanId IN (SELECT TOP (2) PlanId FROM Plan ORDER BY CreateDate DESC)
```

If you put that into the filter for each table it will only replicate the rows for those 2 plans.

To use multiple columns for the filter, something like this "should" work.  I haven't tested this, so it might take some tweaking to make it happen.

```
WHERE PlanId IN (   
        SELECT PlanId FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId, PlanId ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) RowId,
            PlanId, ClientId
            FROM [Plan] a
            where [Plan].PlanId = a.PlanId
                and [Plan].ClientId = a.ClientID
            ) b
        WHERE b.RowId IN (1,2)
        )
```

Comment: Sweet, close!  I just need to rework this to be the TOP 2 Plans for each ClientID(a coulumn in tblPlan).  Sometimes I think you may be the only human in the WORLD that knows anything about Replication.  I believe you have been the only one to answer every single one of my repl questions.  Thank you, thank you.

Comment: Can you reference a view in the WHERE of a filter?

Comment: Yes you can reference a view in a WHERE clause.

To do top to for each customer you'll need to use the ROW_NUMBER function.  I'll update my answer.